# Error: pdf does not look like a valid pdf document. Either the file is corrupt or it is in the process of creation. Retrying every two seconds

Tags: pdftex

I am working on TeXmaker and all of the sudden this message popped up (this problem occured after closing and re-opening the program and the code is correct, there i no error inside of it). I tried to run the same code on TeXstudio but it gave me the same problem.
I tried to search everywhere in the internet to see if there was a similar cases, but all of theme were useless or not exactly like mine.
I get the same message also for older files and new ones. This makes me guess that this is a problem of MiKTeX since it doesn't compile neither on TexMaker and TeXstudio.
I tried to use the command prompt as suggested on reddit (I wrote "pdflatex *filename*"), but I really don't know how to exploit this feature.

Do you have any idea of what could cause this problem?

Comment: Delete all of the files except for the tex file.  At the command prompt, type `pdflatex filename`.  What happens?  (Which operating system are you using?)

Comment: If you have a `build` (not `build and view`) option, use that and look for error messages.